# Invalid scope for ComputeManagementClient for Azure US Government account?

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-gov

I'm trying to create a simple script that lists out the virtual machines on my Azure US Government account. However, I am faced with this error:

```
azure.core.exceptions.ClientAuthenticationError: DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
Attempted credentials:
    VisualStudioCodeCredential: Azure Active Directory error '(invalid_scope) AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope https://management.azure.com/.default https://management.core.usgovcloudapi.net/.default is not valid. static scope limit exceeded.
```

This is the code I have used:

```
def get_access_to_virtual_machine():
    subscription_id = key.SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    credentials = DefaultAzureCredential(authority = AZURE_US_GOV_CLOUD.endpoints.active_directory, 
                                        tenant_id = key.TENANT_ID,
                                        exclude_environment_credential = True,
                                        exclude_managed_identity_credential = True,
                                        exclude_shared_token_cache_credential = True)               
    compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credential = credentials, 
                                            subscription_id = subscription_id, 
                                            base_url = AZURE_US_GOV_CLOUD.endpoints.resource_manager,
                                            credential_scopes = [AZURE_US_GOV_CLOUD.endpoints.active_directory_resource_id + '.default'])
    return compute_client

def get_azure_vm(resource_group_name, virtual_machine_name):
    compute_client = get_access_to_virtual_machine()
    vm_data = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(resource_group_name, 
                                                virtual_machine_name, 
                                                expand = 'instanceView')
    return vm_data
```

I have signed into my Azure US Government account using Visual Studio as well. The error stems from the `compute_client.virtual_machines.get()` command. I am 100% sure the credentials I am using are correct but I am really stuck on this. I've tried using `ClientSecretCredential` instead of `DefaultAzureCredential` and ran into the same `ClientAuthenticationError`. In addition, I'm not sure where this `scope` parameter that the error mentions should be passed in.

Comment: Can you use postman to do a test? Then give me a screenshot of the test result.

Answer (score 0):

For Azure Subscriptions management, the scope should be `{management-endpoint}/user_impersonation` and not `{management-endpoint}/.default`. For example, in Azure Commercial the scope will be `https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation`.

I'm not 100% sure but the management endpoint for Azure Government is either `https://management.usgovcloudapi.net/` or `https://management.core.usgovcloudapi.net/`. Based on the correct endpoint, your scope value should be either `https://management.usgovcloudapi.net/user_impersonation` or `https://management.core.usgovcloudapi.net/user_impersonation`.

Please try by changing that.

**UPDATE**

Looking at the GitHub issue [`here`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/16688), it seems there's an issue with the SDK itself. Please try the solution proposed [`here`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/16688#issuecomment-777588358).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried using `user_impersonation` instead of `.default` in the `credential_scopes` parameter but was met with a similar error: `VisualStudioCodeCredential: Azure Active Directory error '(invalid_scope) AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope https://management.azure.com/.default https://management.core.usgovcloudapi.net/user_impersonation is not valid. .default scope can't be combined with resource-specific scopes.`. Do you have any suggestions on this?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. HTH. Do post your final solution if you are able to make it work. It will definitely help other folks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of the Python SDK you have, but I was able to load the latest modules and get the following code to run in the Azure US Government cloud and pull back VM data:

```
import os
from msrestazure.azure_cloud import AZURE_US_GOV_CLOUD as CLOUD
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

subscription_id = 'xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx'
tenant_id = 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'
resource_group_name = 'rgName'
vm_name = 'vmName'

credential = DefaultAzureCredential(
    authority=CLOUD.endpoints.active_directory, 
    tenant_id=tenant_id)

compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(
    credential, subscription_id, 
    base_url=CLOUD.endpoints.resource_manager,
    credential_scopes=[CLOUD.endpoints.resource_manager + '/.default'])

vm_data = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(
    resource_group_name, 
    vm_name, 
    expand = 'instanceView')

print(f"{vm_data.name}")
```

Some things to note:

- You had a few of the authentication methods set as excluded, you may want to ensure the method you are expecting is not excluded
- The latest SDK sets the environment in the import, I set it to "CLOUD" so that the same code can be used for various cloud by simply changing the import statement
- The latest SDK does seem to want '/.default' as part of the credential_scopes